# Apache serves old versions of files

Tags: apache2, cache-control

I am debugging js code on localhost and I need to prevent the caching of files by the browser.  I can't use a timestamp appended to the url because it erases chrome debugger breakpoints.

Usually I don't have to refresh the cache, but everyone in a while I do. It is a large problem because I go searching elsewhere for the bugs. I added this code to apache some time ago:

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header add Expires "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT"
            Header add Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
    </IfModule>
```

Can someone explain why Apache would mistake a file for valid or provide some additions to the configuration code that could fix this once and for all?

Headers using the solution below:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  expiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
</IfModule>

http://localhost/static/images/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f%20logo_inner.png

GET /static/images/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f%20logo_inner.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/static/images/
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:33:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 17:32:51 GMT
Etag: "b3c27-f1f-4c38bb88d96c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3871
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:33:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 17:32:51 GMT
Etag: "b3c27-f1f-4c38bb88d96c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3871
Cache-Control: max-age=1
Expires: Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:33:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png




The second request:

http://localhost/static/images/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f%20logo_inner.png

GET /static/images/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f%20logo_inner.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/static/images/
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 17:32:51 GMT
If-None-Match: "b3c27-f1f-4c38bb88d96c0"
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:34:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Etag: "b3c27-f1f-4c38bb88d96c0"
Expires: Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:34:59 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=1
```

Comment: This question is on topic because it is regarding a tool that programmers use. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When delivering static files, Apache sends an ETag header, which is something like a checksum of the file. The browser will cache the file and remember the ETag, which is sent with the next request.

If the file changes the browser ETag should differ and the webserver should resend, when the etag is equal, the webserver will respond with `304 Not Modified`. The ETag mechanism has a higher priority than other cache headers.

To disable etags you can use apaches

```
FileETag None
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#fileetag

Wikipedia has a nice article about the Etag header
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

**Edit**

This should be a waterproof configuration

```
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
```

Don't forget that configuration changes require a server restart to take effect.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

**EDIT2**

Wrap filesMatch around the configuration to disable caching for specific file extensions only

```
<filesMatch ".(php|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    [..]
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work as you intended (I still get the 304 header). I even also tried adding

Header unset Pragma
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Comment: Delete the browsers cache once and make sure the ETag is actually no longer set by apache (correct configuration)

Comment: The ETag is definitely being sent by Apache. I don't know how to correct the configuration because I added those lines to my Virtual Host file as you said and as other tutorials say.

Comment: Added a configuration example above which should work in every case

Comment: It worked, thanks. Also, is there a way to make this only for .js,.css, and .php?

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your requirement correctly you want the web browser to not remember anything about the webpage you are accessing and your apache web server should treat it like a fresh page request. You may first want to enable mod_expires and mod_headers , i  use ubuntu so mine was

```
a2enmod headers && a2enmod expires && service apache2 restart
```

than you want to add below code to do minimum cache-control,

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  expiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

If you are using firefox you can test this by installing/running Live Http header Plugin or if you are linux/unix you can run this request with **curl -v** your_url

Comment: I tested this with the liveheaders and attached the debug output. On the second attempt the file is loaded from the cache.